# error installing to parse

Tags: jsf, java-ee-6, jboss6.x

i create a hello world page .jsp 
i work on eclipse with jboss6/jee6/jsf
i make all the configuration with the add of libary but its not working

```
10:18:23,141 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfsfile:/C:/j2eePFE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1303309133687/deploy/MonProjet.war/ state=PreParse mode=Manual requiredState=Parse: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfsfile:/C:/j2eePFE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1303309133687/deploy/MonProjet.war/
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:362)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:322)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:294)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:234)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1660)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1378)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1319)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:378)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2029)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1050)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1289)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1213)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1107)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:918)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:633)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:898)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:677)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:409)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jsp-version'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":short-name}' is expected. @ vfszip:/C:/j2eePFE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1303309133687/deploy/MonProjet.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl.jar/META-INF/mojarra_ext.tld[43,18]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:203)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:168)
    at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:229)
    at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:206)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:137)
    at org.jboss.deployment.TldParsingDeployer.parse(TldParsingDeployer.java:64)
    at org.jboss.deployment.TldParsingDeployer.parse(TldParsingDeployer.java:38)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:121)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.handleMultipleFiles(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:397)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:282)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:355)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jsp-version'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":short-name}' is expected. @ vfszip:/C:/j2eePFE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1303309133687/deploy/MonProjet.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl.jar/META-INF/mojarra_ext.tld[43,18]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser$MetaDataErrorHandler.error(SaxJBossXBParser.java:426)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:199)
    ... 39 more
```

please any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an invalid TLD. What version of Mojarra are you using? This is possibly [this bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1030).

JBoss 6 ships with a version of JSF 2 in the container (this is a requirement of the Java EE 6 Web Profile.) You should be able to delete any jsf-api and jsf-impl jars within your WAR.

Comment: i didnt really understand the question but i change to glassfish v3 and is not working and i installed another time jdk 6 it generate more errors i will download another version of eclipse

Comment: @user726991 - the issue is that there is a broken TLD file in one of the JARs in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Since you are using containers with built-in JSF 2 support, it is unlikely that you need to include your own JSF implementation in the WAR file.

Comment: i download again the jars but it still the same thing

Comment: @user726991 - you do not need the JSF jars; delete them